# Loading multiple Shared Libraries at run time does not work in Android

Tags: android, cmake, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am using cmake to create my Shared Libraries in Android Studio. The Libraries build and link correctly and I am able to see all my Libraries in the Apk under lib/armeabi-v7a.

The libraries are linked as follows:

- Lib1

  - Lib2

    - Lib3

      - Lib4
      - Lib5

I have loaded my Lib1 by making a call to `System.loadLibrary("lib1");`

I am able to make calls to Lib1, but as soon as Lib1 tries to access Lib2, I get a propagated message saying Lib2 was not loaded.

I then figured I had to load the other libs, so I made the following calls but ended up with the same propagated message "Lib2 not loaded".

```
System.loadLibrary("lib5");
System.loadLibrary("lib4");
System.loadLibrary("lib3");
System.loadLibrary("lib2");
System.loadLibrary("lib1");
```

Why would Lib1 be failing to call Lib2? Are additional shared libs unpacked in a location that is causing the library load to fail?

I would like to note that I had my libs loading correctly before switching to use cmake. I believe I was previously manually compiling my libs and storing them in the /jniLibs and /assets directories in my Android Studio project, but that was a while ago so my memory is not clear on the details.

Comment: I've notices a lot of people talking about using this /libs directory in their projects file structure. I do not have the /libs directory in my module, but that might be due to the fact that this is an older project.

Comment: Is it possible to have a module for each library and tie them together with module dependencies? What kind of module would I require for this?

Comment: @ Brendan Cordingley lib directory of native .so file are automatically generated when you build your native files, You can have different .So file for the different module and you can include them also.

Answer (score 5):

Since your change appears to be taking effect, I'll guess this isn't some accident like putting the binaries in the wrong place. (I myself have sometimes uploaded to `jniLibs/armeabi-v7a` then realized I was testing the 64-bit APK that relies on `jniLibs/arm64-v8a`. Or the other way around when installing a dual-architecture apk on a 32-bit Android device.)

I guess we can rule out an unresolved symbol at load time as well, because it'll typically tell you about that in `adb logcat`

I recall when seeing this problem in the past it usually turned out to be an issue of lib2's **soname**. While PC Linux may work with something like `liblib2.so.1`, Android seems to require that all sonames end in `.so`

To check the soname on lib2, run `readelf -a liblib2.so`. If it appears incorrect as I've described, redo your NDK build and ensure that `-Wl,-soname,liblib2.so` is added at link time.

Furthermore, run `readelf -a liblib1.so` and make sure its reference to liblib2.so uses the new soname e.g. `(NEEDED) Shared Library: [liblib2.so]`. You may need to re-link liblib1.so as well.

> I would like to note that I had my libs loading correctly before switching to use cmake.

I'll assume CMake was used for the NDK stage of the build and not Java, which could explain a change in the soname.

Note: It's a bit confusing that you put an additional "lib" in each library's given names. It might have been easier to communicate had you used an example that did `System.loadLibrary("1")`, `System.loadLibrary("2")`

Comment: I've checked the soname and it looks correct. It is possible that I accidentally introduced 64bit/32bit compatibility bug. I will review my process and post my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Gradle file, this could be because AS only executes the last cmake file listed in an `externalNativeBuild` statement.

You can look inside your APK to check which libraries are actually being built and bundled in. If you change the apk extension to a .zip, then unzip and look into the `lib` directory, you'll find a list of build directories, which contain .so files. If you don't see the .so corresponding to a `System.loadLibrary(<libName>);` call, you'll receive runtime errors.

A problem that caused a similar issue **for me** is that I was trying to use multiple cmake files corresponding to each library I wanted to include, by using `externalNativeBuild` in my app's Gradle build file like so:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists1.txt"
        path "CMakeLists2.txt"
    }
}
```

And I noticed that **only the last CMakeLists.txt** listed in that statement is executed. This resulted in only one .so file to be output to my APK's `lib` directory, not both as I'd intended. I believe the intention for AS is to reference only one cmake file in that statement. If you are referencing more, as I did, it's probably only building the last one, so the others (in your case, everything after "lib1") would be missing.